# is there a way to tell what mod an item/block originates from?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-industrialcraft, minecraft-thaumcraft

I have a number of mods and I know some of them added copper to the world. When mining I tend to find 2 kinds of copper ore, ones with orange dots (Copper A) and ones with [goldenrod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldenrod_%28color%29#Goldenrod) dots (Copper B).

When I smelt these two ores I get 2 different ingots. In IndustrialCraft when I crush Copper B Ore I get Crushed Copper Ore and when smelted I get what I would have gotten if I smelted Copper A ore.

Now I've been storing Copper A Ingots as blocks in my factory as I suspect that Copper B was added by RailCraft. When I went to get some of Copper A out of a block the ingots I got were a totally different colour to Copper A or B (but I could flatten it to make wires just the same as Copper A).

Now I would like to know which mod created not only the third copper ingot but the two different types of Tin Ore I've been getting. So I am wondering, **is there a way to check what mod a particular block/item came from in game?**

Comment: Sounds like you have three mod instances going on. Do you have ThermalFoundation and COFH core installed as well? That adds Copper, Tin, Lead, Ferrous, Silver and Shiny ores into World Gen which may also explain the sudden appearance of Copper Ingot C

Comment: Use the mod Waila!

Comment: OT: You should consider to get some mod that generates ALL ores, like GregTech, PFAA Geologica, or something like COFH core (?) , letting it to generate all ores and disable all other ore worldgen, so it will result in one type of every mineral, which is really good thing to aim. Also for example GregTech can easily unify all the ingots into one type so you don't need to deal with more types.  (But yeah, it is quite big mod)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to see the mod, one easy one hard:

1. Install NEI, it will display the mod the item came from in the tool tip
2. Use the Open Block Donation Station. If you put the item in it will link you to the mod/mod author's page so you can determine the source.

On a side note, with most mods the ores are registered with Forge Ore Dictionary, so when you crush Copper A or B the machine will take it and converts it into Crushed Copper Ore.